Why is the novel called David Copperfield?
In chapter 14 of David Copperfield, the eponymous narrator is adopted by his great-aunt, Betsey Trotwood. She decides to rename him:

     "I have been thinking, do you know, Mr. Dick, that I might call him Trotwood?"
     "Certainly, certainly. Call him Trotwood, certainly," said Mr. Dick. "David's son Trotwood."
     "Trotwood Copperfield, you mean," returned my aunt.
     "Yes, to be sure. Yes. Trotwood Copperfield," said Mr. Dick, a little abashed.
Dickens, Charles. David Copperfield. 1850. Introduction by David Gates. Notes by Nitin Govil. New York: Modern Library, 2000. p. 201.

This metonymy is immediately effected. Miss Trotwood, her roommate Mr Dick, Mr Wickfield the lawyer with whom the boy lodges while at school, etc., all call him "Trotwood" or "Trot." The chapter titles reinforce this sense of a new identity: Chapter 15 is "I Make Another Beginning"; Chapter 16, "I am a New Boy in More Senses than One." So: given that the narrator is only ten years old when this happens, and the narrative takes him to adulthood, why does the title deadname him? Why is the novel not called Trotwood Copperfield?

This makes more sense when considering how Dickens' works were published.  They were not published as complete novels, but released as serial installments.  The title was decided and fixed upon publishing the first installment, while the name change didn't happen until chapter 14 as noted in your question, which was part of the fifth installment.
The title was actually chosen because the initials of the protagonist were an inverse of Dickens' own initials.
--SOURCES--
The information behind this answer can be found in the wikipedia page on David Copperfield.  Which is rather well sourced.  The title choice information is from a Dickens contemporary John Forster who talked to Dickens about the title and pointed out the initials upon which Dickens declared it must be fate and finalized the title.  Forster wrote a book about Dickens titled: The Life of Charles Dickens written in 1875 and available at Project Gutenberg.

David allows Aunt Betsey and the people he meets through her to call him Trotwood, but (spoiler alert!)
when he later lives and works in London he evidently uses his original name, since Dora calls him 'Doady' as a pet-name for David. Dickens doesn't spell this out, we just have to assume that it is so.

@verbose I'm a bit curious why you rolled back the edit that add spoiler block properly.

@AndrewT. Spoilers are inaccessible to keyboard-only users.

@AndrewT. What Tsundoku said

Perhaps I needn't have called it a spoiler anyway - I did so in case the OP was still reading the book.

@verbose It's not really fair to claim "this site avoids [spoilertags]", nor to add such a warning to someone else's answer, when so far it's just 2 people in comments expressing anti-spoilertag views, and seemingly at least 4 who are pro-spoilertag (2 editors, 1 edit-approver, 1 commenter). Let's try to get a meta consensus on this (I'll post on meta shortly), and then it'll be more clear how to proceed.
